# helm - adding helm-M-x to helm sources

Tags: elisp, helm, m-x

I am able to add few extra sources to helm like this

```
(setq helm-mini-default-sources '(helm-source-buffers-list
                                  helm-source-recentf
                                  helm-source-dired-recent-dirs
                                  helm-chrome-source
                                  hgs/helm-c-source-stars
                                  hgs/helm-c-source-repos
                                  hgs/helm-c-source-search
                                  helm-source-buffer-not-found))
```

The last thing i need to add to this is `helm-M-x`. I just need to add all commands to default sources. By this i can invoke a single function and I can go to anything or i can invoke any command.

But `helm-M-x` is a function and its source-code doesn't have any sources. Any help on how to achieve this?

Comment: Why about creating Emacs commands source by yourself?

Comment: As I'm unable to leave this as a comment due to >50 reputation, I'd just like to add for 2022 helm the only change needed to the above answers is to convert the symbol to a string before pushing onto the alist, else helm-flex--style-score will complain. (push (symbol-name elt) cmds)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(defvar helm-source-emacs-commands
  (helm-build-sync-source "Emacs commands"
    :candidates (lambda ()
                  (let ((cmds))
                    (mapatoms
                     (lambda (elt) (when (commandp elt) (push elt cmds))))
                    cmds))
    :coerce #'intern-soft
    :action #'command-execute)
  "A simple helm source for Emacs commands.")

;; Try it
(helm :sources helm-source-emacs-commands)
```

Comment: i tried to build another source just like this https://gist.github.com/ChillarAnand/23119413409f00b7e995#file-helm-el but it didn't work as expected?

Comment: I've tried yours, it works fine, but just for the histroy of Emacs commands, so you have to use `helm-M-x` to run some commands to build that history first, because helm doesn't save history across session by default.

Answer (score 4):

Based on xuchunyang's answer, I was able to add `helm-M-x` to helm sources.

```
(defvar helm-source-emacs-commands
  (helm-build-sync-source "Emacs commands"
    :candidates (lambda ()
                  (let ((cmds))
                    (mapatoms
                     (lambda (elt) (when (commandp elt) (push elt cmds))))
                    cmds))
    :coerce #'intern-soft
    :action #'command-execute)
  "A simple helm source for Emacs commands.")

(defvar helm-source-emacs-commands-history
  (helm-build-sync-source "Emacs commands history"
    :candidates (lambda ()
                  (let ((cmds))
                    (dolist (elem extended-command-history)
                      (push (intern elem) cmds))
                    cmds))
    :coerce #'intern-soft
    :action #'command-execute)
  "Emacs commands history")

(setq helm-mini-default-sources '(helm-source-emacs-commands-history
                                  helm-source-emacs-commands))
```

Comment: Great, this helps me a lot for helm-for-files.